# Rolling Daily Distinct Counts Partition by Month

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id      int NOT NULL
, date    date NOT NULL
, cid     int NOT NULL
);
 
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1 , '2022-01-01', 1)
, (2 , '2022-01-01', 1)
, (3 , '2022-01-01', 2)
, (4 , '2022-01-01', 3)
, (5 , '2022-01-02', 1)
, (6 , '2022-01-02', 4)
, (7 , '2022-01-03', 5)
, (8 , '2022-01-03', 6)
, (9 , '2022-02-01', 1)
, (10, '2022-02-01', 5)
, (11, '2022-02-02', 5)
, (12, '2022-02-02', 3)
;
```

I'm trying to count distinct users `(= cid)` each day, but the result is rolling during the month. E.g., for `2022-01-01`, only distinct users with `date = 2022-01-01` are counted. For `2022-01-02`, distinct users with `date between 2022-01-01 and 2022-01-02` are counted, and so on. The count should restart each month.

My desired output:

```
   date        distinct_cids
2022-01-01           3
2022-01-02           4
2022-01-03           6
2022-02-01           2
2022-02-02           3
```

Comment: can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: @lemon the only way I can think of doing this is using window functions. I get an error saying I cannot use distinct in a window frame or order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to snowflake so I can't guarantee that this will work, but from the sound of it:

```
select date, count(distinct cid) over (partition by month(date) order by date) 
from tbl
order by date;
```

If you have several years worth of data, you can partition by year, month:

```
select date, count(distinct cid) over (partition by year(date), month(date) order by date) 
from tbl
order by date;
```

Date is a reserved word, so you may consider renaming your column

EDIT: Since distinct is disallowed you can try a vanilla SQL variant. It is likely slow for a large table:

```
select dt, count(cid)
from (
    select distinct dt.dt, x.cid
    from tbl x
    join (
        select distinct date as dt from tbl
    ) dt (dt)
        on x.date <= dt.dt 
        and month(x.date) = month(dt.dt)
) t
group by dt
order by dt   
;
```

The idea is that we create a new relation (t) with distinct users with a date less than or equal to the current date in the current month. Then we can just count those users for each date.

Comment: This was my initial try as well, but I get this error message, "distinct cannot be used with a window frame or an order."

Comment: Unless I misread the documentation it should be supported: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count.html  but I do know that many DBMS disallow it

Comment: @tmul, I updated my answer with a vanilla sql92 solution

Comment: your edit code works perfectly. Thanks. I just don't get this part `on x.date <= dt.dt`. Why `<=` specifically?

Comment: We do want to include cid from the current date. < would be cids before current date. If you remove the outermost select and look at the relation t, I think you will see it

Comment: I have added a db<>fiddle for first 2 dates at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5c13a80394c582fbcb639f320da2573